# ¿Cómo eliminar todos los atributos de un elemento usando pyQuery?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Con el objetivo de conocer el funcionamiento de [pyquery](http://pyquery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (una librería similar a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) para Python), he creado un pequeño script que lo que hace (por ahora) es agregar ciertas clases CSS a una tabla HTML de acuerdo al Framework que se le indica ([Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/)):

```
import os
import sys

from pyquery import PyQuery as pq


BOOTSTRAP = 'bootstrap'
MATERIALIZE = 'materialize'
FRAMEWORKS = [
    BOOTSTRAP,
    MATERIALIZE
]


def show_available_frameworks():
    print 'Available frameworks:'
    for fw in FRAMEWORKS:
        print '- %s' % fw.title()

def show_usage():
    print 'Usage: prettify.py /path/to/template framework'


def prettify_html(template_path, framework):
    if not os.path.exists(template_path) or not os.path.isfile(template_path):
        print 'ERROR: template "%s" not found or invalid' % (template_path)
        return 1
    template_content = open(template_path).read()
    dom = pq(template_content)
    if framework == BOOTSTRAP:
        dom('table').add_class('table table-striped')
        dom('th').add_class('text-info')
        dom('th, td').add_class('text-center')
    elif framework == MATERIALIZE:
        dom('table').add_class('striped')
        dom('th').add_class('blue-text text-darken-2')
        dom('th, td').add_class('center-align')
    else:
        show_available_frameworks()
        return 1
    print dom.outer_html()
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        show_usage()
        show_available_frameworks()
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.exit(prettify_html(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

Sencillo, nada del otro mundo. Luego, creé el siguiente archivo HTML con una tabla cuyos elementos no tienen atributos:

```
$ cat table.html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>400</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Probando con Bootstrap:

```
$ python prettify.py table.html bootstrap
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-info text-center">A</th>
            <th class="text-info text-center">B</th>
            <th class="text-info text-center">C</th>
            <th class="text-info text-center">D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">1</td>
            <td class="text-center">2</td>
            <td class="text-center">3</td>
            <td class="text-center">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">10</td>
            <td class="text-center">20</td>
            <td class="text-center">30</td>
            <td class="text-center">40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">100</td>
            <td class="text-center">200</td>
            <td class="text-center">300</td>
            <td class="text-center">400</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Probando con Materialize:

```
$ python prettify.py table.html materialize
<table class="striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="blue-text text-darken-2 center-align">A</th>
            <th class="blue-text text-darken-2 center-align">B</th>
            <th class="blue-text text-darken-2 center-align">C</th>
            <th class="blue-text text-darken-2 center-align">D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="center-align">1</td>
            <td class="center-align">2</td>
            <td class="center-align">3</td>
            <td class="center-align">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center-align">10</td>
            <td class="center-align">20</td>
            <td class="center-align">30</td>
            <td class="center-align">40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="center-align">100</td>
            <td class="center-align">200</td>
            <td class="center-align">300</td>
            <td class="center-align">400</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Lo que quiero lograr ahora es que cada uno de los elementos no tenga ningún atributo, es decir, si en mi función recibo una tabla con lo siguiente:

```
<table class="a b c" style="color: red" data-example="10">
```

Quiero eliminar todos los atributos y dejarla "limpia" antes de agregarle las clases de cada Framework:

```
<table>
```

Puedo usar el método `remove_attr` para eliminar un atributo pero tendría que saber cuáles son exactamente y la idea es eliminarlos todos, ¿es posible hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es, como menciona @Gemasoft, hacer uso del API para crear una función que me permita eliminar los atributos de un elemento.

Lo que he hecho es usar [`Fn`](http://pyquery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#pyquery.pyquery.PyQuery.Fn) para crear la función `remove_all_attrs()`:

```
def remove_attribs(elem):
    for attribute in elem.attrib:
        del elem.attrib[attribute]

def prettify_html(template_path, framework):
    # ...
    fn = lambda: this.map(lambda i, el: remove_attribs(el))
    pq.fn.remove_all_attrs = fn
    # ...
```

Con esa definición, entonces, es posible usarla de esta manera:

```
dom('table').remove_all_attrs()
```

O usando varios elementos:

```
dom('table, thead, tbody, tr, th, td').remove_all_attrs()
```

Answer (score 2):

No es posible hacerlo con funcionalidad nativa.

De acuerdo con la [documentación oficial](http://pyquery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) tendrías que iterar los atributos para después removerlos.

Comment: Si, parece que es la única forma aunque todavía no logro hacerlo